# keras error in model fit ValueError: Shapes (32, 147) and (32, 2) are incompatible

Tags: python, keras

I am trying to train Keras model, below code I am using

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(Conv2D(32, kernel_size=(3, 3),activation='relu',input_shape=(28,28,1)))
model.add(Conv2D(64, (3, 3), activation='relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))
model.add(Dropout(0.25))
model.add(Flatten())
model.add(Dense(128, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dropout(0.5))
model.add(Dense(len(np.unique(y)), activation='softmax'))

model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy',optimizer='Adam',metrics=['accuracy'])

model.fit(X_train, y_train, epochs=10, validation_data=(X_test, y_test))
```

but I am getting error:

```
ValueError: Shapes (32, 147) and (32, 2) are incompatible
```

input and output variable shape are as below.

```
print(f"Input: {X_train.shape}, Output: {y_train.shape}")
Input: (3360, 28, 28, 1), Output: (3360, 147)
```

I tried to use `loss='sparse_categorical_crossentrop'` using 1D integer encoded target , but getting very poor accuracy.
Can anyone please help me.

Comment: You have 3360 samples. Each sample as X has shape (28,28,1) and as Y has (147). Since `y_train.shape` is `(3360,147)`. But your last layer has 2 neurons as output (`len(np.unique(y))` returns 2), therefore they are incompatible. You should specify you have 147 classes or 2 classes.

Comment: @Kaveh You are awesome. Thank you very much for your help, it worked post your suggestion

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your model's output shape is not the same as `y_train`.

You have 3360 samples. Each sample in `X` has shape `(28,28,1)` and in `Y` has `(147)`. But your last layer has 2 neurons as output of `len(np.unique(y)`, and they are incompatible (147 vs. 2).
You should specify that you have 147 classes or 2 classes.

One possible solution:

```
model.add(Dense(147, activation='softmax'))
```